# Custom Post Type Pagination & duplicate posts

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, pagination, duplicates

I'm working on a template which will use some custom-post-types & custom-taxonomies.. I'm having problems with pagination and duplicate posts.

**HOME.PHP**

LOOP #1
On the homepage (home.php) I have 2 Loops. The fist one shows 1 post (custom post type: Projects) which has the custom-taxonomy "Featured" assigned to it.

LOOP #2
On the second loop I have the six most recent "Projects" (Custom post type) but I dont want a duplicate from the first loop. Under the six posts I'd like a pagination

Both loops in home.php work.. but I still have that duplicate and I can't get pagination to work..

**PasteBin**

- home.php: http://pastebin.com/6ac2asue
- functions.php: http://pastebin.com/1SK206Bh

  ```
  <?php $do_not_duplicate = array();
  $folio_loop = new WP_Query( array
      (
          'featured' => 'featured-post',
          'post_type' => 'projects',
          'posts_per_page' => '1',
          )
      );

       while ( $folio_loop->have_posts() ) : $folio_loop->the_post();
      $do_not_duplicate[] = $post->ID; ?>

      <div id="featured" style="position: relative;">


          <div class="featured-overlay" style="position: absolute; right: 20px; bottom: 20px; width: 165px; height: 165px; text-align: center;">
              <div class="project-meta-featured">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" >
          <span>
          <?php
              global $post;
              $text = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_cmb_project_meta', true );
              echo $text;
          ?>
          </span>
          <br />
          <?php
              global $post;
              $text = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_cmb_client_meta', true );
              echo $text;
          ?>


          </a>
            </div>
          </div>

          <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) : ?>
              <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" >
                  <?php the_post_thumbnail('featured'); ?>
              </a>
          <?php endif; ?>



      </div>

  <?php endwhile; ?>
  ```

Comment: - featured.php: http://pastebin.com/2X8xTPTY

Comment: Pleas don't use pastebins. They can get lost. Always reduce it to the necessary part of your question and add this code directly in it.

Comment: your $do_not_duplicate variable is not global so it cannot be shared through different php files. You create it in feature.php and then use it in home.php. The issue is the same for pagination : you are using the global $wp_query instead of the one you create in home.php

Comment: Make sure that `front-page.php` isn't the more appropriate template for this case. It seems like you're using a "Static Front Page" model rather than a News-y page. If that's the case, `front-page.php` is the right template to use in conjunction with Front Page settings in Settings > Reading.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to implement this is to use `pre_get_posts` hook. Take a look at this code

```
function customize_query( $query ) {
    $post = get_posts(array(
         'post_type' => 'projects',
         'taxonomy' => 'featured',
         'numberposts' => 1
    ));
    if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', 'projects' );
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 6 );
        if($post && !empty($post))
            $query->set( 'post__not_in', array($post[0]->ID) );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'customize_query' );
```

Then in your home page

```
$post = get_posts(array(
     'post_type' => 'projects',
     'taxonomy' => 'featured',
     'numberposts' => 1
));
// display the post just retrieved, it must be coming from cache

// we can use the global query since now it contains the 6 posts we want
while(have_posts()) :
    the_post();
    // display the post
endwhile;
```

You'll need to modify it a lot but it might help you achieve what you want. In here the pagination should wotrk as normal since you just modified the main page query

Comment: I tried to implement some parts of your code:  <code>function custom_query( $query ) {
 

 
 if ( is_home()&& is_main_query() ) {
        //Display 6 projects in home
        $query->query_vars['posts_per_page'] = 6;
 $query->set( 'post_type', 'projects' );
        return;
 }

 }
 add_action('pre_get_posts', 'custom_query', 1);</code> It gives me 6 posts and pagination works. BUT I loose my navigation (really why??).  If I paste the code for the featured post in functions.php my apache server crashes (again.. why?)..

Comment: you can't use `is_home()&& is_main_query()`, it's `$query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query()`. & this code can't make server crash, it must be something else

Comment: Ah yes that solved my navigation problem.. I'm running a local server and when I paste    `$post = get_posts(array(
         'post_type' => 'projects',
         'taxonomy' => 'featured',
         'numberposts' => 1
    ));` in functions.php and hit save, I immediately get a message that apache stoped working.

Comment: Honestly, i don't see a reason for server crash. Could you provide more details regarding the problem, maybe provide the code present before & after this code? Where you're getting the message? etc.

Comment: no error in the code. Maybe you should see if this server is having problems somewhere else as well or maybe restart it.